# How do I run a mix task from within a mix task?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I would like to run a mix task from within a custom mix task.

Something like

```
def run(_) do
  Mix.Shell.cmd("mix edeliver build release")
  #do other stuff
```

But I cannot figure out how to execute a shell command. If there is any easier way (besides just making a bash script), let me know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shell is the redundant link here. If you want to run `edeliver` task, run [`Mix.Tasks.Edeliver#run`](https://github.com/boldpoker/edeliver/blob/master/lib/mix/tasks/edeliver.ex#L65):

```
def run(_) do
  Mix.Tasks.Edeliver.run(~w|build release|)
  # do other stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

`Mix.Task.run("edeliver build release")` works

Answer (score 1):

For executing shell comand you can use [Loki](https://github.com/khusnetdinov/loki). You can find functions for shell execution `execute/1`.

And example how I used in Mix.Task for executing other mix tasks:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Sesamex.Gen.Auth do
  use Mix.Task

  import Loki.Cmd
  import Loki.Shell

  @spec run(List.t) :: none()
  def run([singular, plural]) do

    execute("mix sesamex.gen.model #{singular} #{plural}")
    execute("mix sesamex.gen.controllers #{singular}")
    execute("mix sesamex.gen.views #{singular}")
    execute("mix sesamex.gen.templates #{singular}")
    execute("mix sesamex.gen.routes #{singular}")

    # ...
  end
end
```

Or just look how it execute command:

```
@spec execute(String.t, list(Keyword.t)) :: {Collectable.t, exit_status :: non_neg_integer}
def execute(string, opts) when is_bitstring(string) and is_list(opts) do
  [command | args] = String.split(string)
  say IO.ANSI.format [:green, " *   execute ", :reset, string]
  System.cmd(command, args, env: opts)
end
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

While I never tried running a mix task via `Mix.shell.cmd` from inside another mix task and I'm not sure if it's best practice, it seems like something like what you're aiming for would work:

```
def run(args) do
  Mix.Shell.cmd("mix test", fn(output) -> IO.write(output) end)
  # (...)
end
```

The above code does run the tests via `mix test` and prints out their output. Note: the above code is based on Mix 1.3.4, the interface is slightly different in 1.4.0.

What might be a more elegant approach though would be creating a [mix alias](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.3.4/Mix.html#module-aliases) for a "composite" task, consisting of the tasks you depend on and your custom one:

```
# inside mix.exs
def project do
  [
    # (...)
    aliases: [
      "composite.task": [
        "test",
        "edeliver build release",
        "my.custom.task",
      ] 
    ]
  ]
end
```

Now running `mix composite.task` should run the two other tasks before `my.custom.task`.